# Low throughput ONLY in one partition out of 64 partitions in informatica SQ

Tags: informatica-powercenter, throughput

We are fetching millions of records through a source DB using Informatica Powercenter 9.6.1 and we have partitioned the table and fetching the data using partitions.

However , out of 64 partitions only 1 partition has low throughput. Our CPU is 72 threads and nothing is running in parallel to the session.

We understand that 64 partitions is huge but our server is capable of handling it. But low throught put only in 1 random partition is something we dont understand.

Comment: Is it constant and repeatable? Is it the same partition always causing trouble?

Comment: What kind of partition you are using?

Comment: it's pass through partition, it is sometimes repeatable and sometimes the throughput distribution is even.

Comment: @maciejg : No it is very random partition and not the same partition

Comment: So the partition is not an issue. Appartently you're hitting some other limit. Have you checked network throughput? Source DB stats? Can you share the log, where there's the statistics per thread breakdown?

Comment: We checked that the network throughput is low and gradually decreasing for the partition/node which has the issue. Unfortunately we didnt let the sessions complete and which is why we dont have the statistics per thread breakdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your thread might getting killed in between due to some network issue.
So `informatica` lost connectivity.

Comment: Apparently, there was a network issue as some new interface was changed on Oracle Grid and somehow some threads were getting killed and Informatica was losing connectivity.